# Cycle outputs plain text, should be html

Tags: cycle, output

Is this normal behavior?

```
{% for entry in entries %} 
{{ cycle(['<div></div>', '2', '3', '4'], loop.index0) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Results in:

```
&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;

2

3

4
```

is there a way to force the output as it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Twig's ["raw" filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) to prevent the HTML from being escaped

```
{{ cycle(['<div></div>', '2', '3', '4'], loop.index0)|raw }}
```